# Method or data member not found error for Range.Address method

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm very new to VBA, but I am trying to make a program that will offer suggestions for translations when selecting and right-clicking a word in MS Word. I am getting the message "Compile-Error: Method or data member not found" in the code below at Found.Address:

```
Dim Current As String
Dim oSheet As Range
Dim Found As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim oChanges As Worksheet
Dim sFname As String
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application

Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
oExcel.Visible = False
sFname = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\translations.xlsx"
Set oChanges = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=sFname)
Set oSheet = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'Prepping Excel File

Set oSheet = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Current = Selection.Text
With oSheet
     Set Found = .Find(Current)
     If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = Found.Address
        Do
        .................................
```

I copied this format directly from the Range.Find help page for VBA. What am I missing?

Comment: Use [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/). Specify all parameters. Also ensure that `Current = Selection.Text` returns what you think it returns...

Comment: [excel-vba] code is very different from [word-vba] code; particularly in how Word handles the position of insertion vs. Excel's very definitive cell-by-cell range approach. I would recommend that you locate [word-vba] examples and try not to mash the two together.

Comment: You're declaring Found as a Range object in Word, not as an Excel Range object. That might be the root of this specific issue (not only will it refer to something completely unexpected, but it won't implement properties like .Address). Try changing those lines to `Dim oSheet As Excel.Range` and `Dim Found As Excel.Range` and see if that helps with your error.

Comment: Also, if "Current" isn't found, `Found` will be `Nothing`, which does not have an address

Comment: Using Excel.Range fixed the problem. Thank you!